# Deprecating API authentication through query parameters in Github

Tags: c#, authentication, github, oauth

I have recently received an email ragarding that github is deprecating API authentication through query parameters

https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-10-deprecating-auth-through-query-param/

I am using an url similar to,
https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?scope=user:email%20read:user&client_id=

Does using client id as query parameter is also deprecated? If so is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

YES

> Starting on September 8, 2021, using access_token as a query parameter to access the API (as a user or as a GitHub App) or using `client_id/client_secret` to make OAuth app unauthenticated calls will be disabled.

If you want to use a client id, make it in a **header**. For example:

Using client_id/client_secret as a query param,

If you're using an OAuth app's `client_id` and `client_secret` to make unauthenticated calls with a higher rate limit similar to

```
curl "https://api.github.com/user/repos?client_id=my_client_id&client_secret=my_secret_id"
```

Instead, you should use the following format:

```
curl -u my_client_id:my_client_secret https://api.github.com/user/repos
```

Authenticating to the API should be done with [HTTP basic authentication](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/other-authentication-methods#via-oauth-and-personal-access-tokens).